# Can Eclipse CDT do auto-complete when using typedefs?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, autocomplete

For all my code Eclipse's autocomplete function is working fine, except when I use a typedef.

Example code (someclass.hh):

```
typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;

class SomeClass {
 void sort_int_vector(IntVector &iv) {
   iv.//eclipse auto complete does not work. (ctrl-space)
  }
}
```

How can I configure Eclipse to do auto-complete in this case? Or is this not possible?

I use the Ganymede C/C++ (CDT) package for Linux 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me using Galileo, I would have expected this to be working for a couple of releases now.

Check that the CDT is able to find the appropriate include file.  You can check the Includes under the project explorer.

If it isn't finding your includes, check your project properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols.  You can add paths to places to find the headers.  It Just worked for me, the new project wizard set up paths to the cygwin I have on my path.

[image: cdt screenshot]